Where is the GRUB config on Ubuntu 22.04 located?
According to the Ubuntu Wiki about Booting and in the Ubuntu Documentation for GRUB 2,
there is the file  /boot/grub/grub.cfg.lst containing the GRUB config. But I can find no such file.
Where is the GRUB config on Ubuntu 22.04 located?

I suggest you re-read the page; I see "No /boot/grub/menu.lst. It has been replaced by /boot/grub/grub.cfg." on the page, but no reference to grub.cfg.lst on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Configuring%20GRUB%202  (Do note the page compares the older GRUB and the newer GRUB2, and I think you're misunderstanding the bits related to an older grub, but sorry I can't work out what has you confused)

By the way whatever you want to do, you want to edit /etc/default/grub and then run sudo update-grub. See here

There is no mention of /boot/grub/grub.cfg.lst in the sources in your question. If you read Ubuntu Documentation for GRUB 2 carefully, you will see that it says:


No /boot/grub/menu.lst. It has been replaced by /boot/grub/grub.cfg.


This is under the GRUB vs GRUB 2 section, which highlights the differences between GRUB and GRUB 2. It says that in GRUB (not used anymore by Ubuntu) the config was in /boot/grub/menu.lst, while in GRUB 2 (which Ubuntu 22.04 uses) the config is in /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
So there's your answer basically: The GRUB config in Ubuntu 22.04 is in /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
